# Foreign Key Settings

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, referential-integrity

I will start by mentioning that I am very new to databases. I am working in MySQL.

Can anyone give me a layman's view of when you would use which settings for the foreign key options so when you would use On Delete: Cascade, On Delete: Set Null, On Delete: No Action. Also, how would these work in the sense of foreign keys in a bridging table, does it depend on the context of the database as in what data it contains or is there a general rule of thumb as to which setting is best in this type of relationship?

If you can, please state it simply as I am not totally au fait with the jargon given I am a relative newbie. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use databases without knowing anything about `FOREIGN KEYs` and not using them at all.  I recommend you start that way.

A `FOREIGN KEY` does three things:

- It is a constraint.  It will slap your hand if you try to link from one table to another without there being an appropriate row.  Think of it like filling out a form that calls for your home address, but you mis-type it and there is no house at the address you typed.  If you never make typos, you don't need that check.
- It provides an index (aka "key") to make the above check.  But you can create indexes as needed without having FKs.  And if your tables are only a few hundreds of rows each, you might not notice that you are missing the significant performance benefits of indexes.  An index is like a phonebook.  (If you are too young to know what a phonebook is, visit a museum.)
- It can "cascade" things.  Don't use that; just do it yourself.  I'm referring to the deletion of a row in one table automatically causing the deletion of a corresponding row in another table.  Analogy:  When a person dies, the DMV, the voter registration, the bank, etc, need to be notified manually so they can delete that person from their lists.  FKs facilitate having that happen automatically.

Since you mentioned a bridging table, I'll ramble on in that direction.  (It sounds like you may have already mastered it.)  There are 3 types of "relations" between "entities":

- 1:1 -- Don't use that.  Why bother having two tables that march in lock step when one would do.  (There exceptions; but that comes in another lecture.)
- 1:many -- This is simply implemented with a link ("id") in one table to allow "JOINing" to another table.  Many rows of the first table link to a single row in the second table.
- many:many -- This has many names, "bridging" on one of them.  In the college example:  students:classes, classes:teachers, etc.  Bridging requires an extra table.  See this for the optimal indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Any of those mappings can degenerate to 1 or to 0.

Rambling on...

```
SELECT ... FROM tableA JOIN tableB ON ...
```

delivers rows that show up in both tables (based on the `ON` condition).

```
SELECT ... FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON ...
```

delivers all the rows of table A, whether are not there is a matching row in table B.  If none exists, then the columns that should have come from tableB will be `NULLs`.

The `ON` says how the tables are 'related'.

The `WHERE` clause, if present, filters out some of the rows.

Comment: Thanks, that's very clear. Although I have already been using them, all on the no action setting. I am working on a project, hence asking the question, so would be interested in hearing about what the thoughts are on when one should use which setting and why.

Comment: @portis123 - I have read thousands of questions here, and answered many of them.  Newbies feel obligated to use FKs.  Experienced users tend to use `NO ACTION`.  Everyone gets into some kind of trouble -- usually because the order of creating tables and applying FKs is critical.  (I started using databases before FKs existed; I am still not enamored with them.  Caution:  I may be the odd-ball.)

Comment: @portis123 - "which setting and why" -- My _opinionated_ answer is "none of them" and "take care of cascading (etc) yourself".  (I'm surprised no one has come along to argue the other side.)

Comment: @portis123 - I _think_, but am _not_ sure:  If you `DELETE` from the bridge table, no action should be taken on the other tables -- you are just removing a relation.  If you `DELETE` from one of the other tables, it makes sense to `DELETE` from the bridge table.  But no `CASCADE`.

Comment: @portis123 - re "type of relationship" - A bridge table is (usually) a single "type".  However, consider `movies` and `persons`:  The bridge table could qualify the relationship as `director`, 'actor', etc.  So there could be multiple rows for the same movie and person.  The `INDEXes` should change accordingly; the FKs become too complex for to envision.

Comment: "I think, but am not sure: If you DELETE from the bridge table, no action should be taken on the other tables -- you are just removing a relation. If you DELETE from one of the other tables, it makes sense to DELETE from the bridge table. But no CASCADE" So in this case, are you saying it should be set to No Action and delete the relevant parent entry and then the relevant child entry/ies manually? I still am a little confused on how it works, I assume it should disappear from the bridging table once the relevant parent entry from one of the parent tables is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a table of users and a table of photos and photos has a foreign key column referencing the `user_id` that corresponds to the unique ids of each user in the users table.

With **ON DELETE CASCADE** - when you delete a user when a photo is still referencing it, it will also the delete the photo.

With **ON DELETE SET NULL** - the row of the foreign key column of the photos table for the deleted user will be set to **NULL** as the users' unique id no longer existed because you deleted them.

So where would we want to use this? Well, this might be very useful if a user were to create some kind of resource and if for some reason you delete the user, but you still want to show the underlying photo. Maybe you need to delete a problematic user, but the posts might be meaningful so that might be a scenario where you want to hold the records around even if you deleted some other record that these things depend upon.